# Sharepoint Designer 2010 Workflow Error

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow, error, designer

I'm working on Workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2010.

in past it always work fine and publish no problem. Until this morning I receive an error when publish Workflow.

"Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run." Advanced: Unexpected Error on server associating the workflow.

I've tried google and fix but still same problem. Please can you assist?

Comment: is it Sharepoint on prem or online?

Comment: It is Sharepoint 2010. Old I know.

Comment: I've check. I'm not sure which version.

Comment: I also experienced the same issue and have logged case to Microsoft. They acknowledged this issue is affecting multiple tenants and is working on an update by 23 March

Answer (score 0):

it depends really what is the reason behind compiler error, but lately, this has been the reason
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2018/09/13/after-installing-net-security-patches-to-address-cve-2018-8421-sharepoint-workflows-stop-working/

.NET updates break some assemblies where they are not marked as safe.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SharePoint Designer 2010 workflows in SharePoint Online? If yes, you can check below:

Since 3/7/2019, SharePoint Designer 2010 workflows stopped working on SharePoint Online sites, this issue is logged at Office 365 Admin Center > Health > Service Health > Advisories > SharePoint Online. Currently, it has not been fixed. If you meet this issue in your thread, you can suggest customers to check service health and wait for update.

After the above, you also should check the issue in Service health frequently, once this issue is fixed, please update it to your customers in your thread.

If you are using SharePoint Server, please tell us.